# How do I use Cross Entropy to evaluate my model

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model, cross-entropy

Can i get a CE score just like F1 score? I have been searching for a concise solution I am new to this? I saw this paper where Cross entropy was computed as the evaluation metric but it not clear how to implement this. I have searched hugging face and pytorch but i haven't found a straightforward answer. Thanks

Comment: Cross-entropy is implemented in pytorch, the docs are quite informative.  Note that it is almost exclusively used as a loss function than an accuracy metric.  https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html